# Getting request object in a spring singleton bean

Tags: java, spring, request, httprequest, singleton-type

I have a spring's `singleton bean` and i need to access the request object in that bean. I tried Autowiring the `HttpServletRequest` in the singleton bean :

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

...

public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
  this.request = request;
}

public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
  return request;
}
```

But than i realized it wont work, because the class is acting as a singleton bean (Object will be created once per bean container)

Then i searched for an alternative, and found a code snipet

```
 ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
```

which was supposed to work, but didn't succeeded.

Is there any other way to go through this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Access `HttpServeletRequest` Object in `Singleton Bean` :

First write a simple filter like below and configure it in web.xml
You can make the intercepted URL of your choice below it is configured to /* which will be filtered to all url patterns.

**Create a class Context**

```
public class Context {  
  private static ThreadLocal<Context> instance = new ThreadLocal<Context>();  
  private HttpServletRequest request;  
  private Context(HttpServletRequest request) {  
       this.request = request;  
  }  
  public static Context getCurrentInstance() {  
       return instance.get();  
  }  
  public static Context newInstance(HttpServletRequest request) {  
       Context context = new Context(request);  
       instance.set(context);  
       return context;  
  }  
  public void release() {  
       instance.remove();  
  }  
  public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {  
       return request;  
  }  
 }
```

**Create a filter "RequestAccessFilter.java"**

```
public class RequestAccessFilter implements Filter {  
  @Override  
  public void destroy() {  
       // Nothing Needed            
  }  
  @Override  
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
       Context context = Context.newInstance((HttpServletRequest) request);  
       try {  
         chain.doFilter(request, response);  
       } finally {  
         context.release();  
       }  
  }  
  @Override  
  public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {  
       // Nothing Needed  
  }  
 }
```

**configure the filter in "web.xml"**

```
 <filter>  
    <filter-name>requestAccessFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>com.myapp.web.filter.RequestAccessFilter</filter-class>  
 </filter>  
 <filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>requestAccessFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </filter-mapping>
```

**In Your Bean Class you can access**

```
HttpServletRequest request = Context.getCurrentInstance().getRequest();
```